# Is considered a bouncer if a batsman hits it?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating

Suppose a bowler bowls a shoulder height ball at the batsman and the batsman hits a four or gets out. Can the ball be called as a bouncer?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking: Is it considered a bouncer *if a bowler bowls a shoulder height ball?* or *a batsman hits a bouncer ball* anything else?

Comment: Do you mean will it be declared a no ball?

Answer (score 3):

The law/meaning of the bouncer **is** *the ball bounces above shoulder height* irrespective of a batsman hits it or not. So it is considered a bouncer even if a batsman hits it and gets runs or out.

Answer (score -1):

As per **ICC rules**, Bouncer is declared when bowler bowls above batman's shoulder height.Because its pretty obvious that if ball is above shoulder height, Batman might be not able to play it.

So Everytime when bowler bowls above shoulder height, Leg umpier straight away declare it as **NO BALL** wheather batman hits it or not.

Comment: This answer is incorrect a bouncer must be over head height to be no balled instantly.  It would need to meet the criteria under the laws for the bowlers end umpire to no ball and warn.